# Delete rows from all tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with more than 100 tables. About 20 of them have a specific column, say `column1`.

Can I delete rows **in all tables**, `where column1="abc"`, without specifying each table?

So I need something like this:

```
DELETE FROM [all tables] WHERE column1 = 'abc';
```

Comment: You need create a dinamic query. using `information_schema`  to get the tables with `column1`

Comment: Just query on information schema, get the table names with the row in question, and construct the query.  No need to jump through hoops for this, unless you need to run this query multiple times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way may be the following:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('DELETE FROM ',TABLE_NAME," WHERE column1 = 'abc';") comd
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
AND COLUMN_NAME ='column1';
```

This query will give you output like below:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_1 WHERE column1 = 'abc';
DELETE FROM TABLE_2 WHERE column1 = 'abc';
DELETE FROM TABLE_3 WHERE column1 = 'abc';
DELETE FROM TABLE_4 WHERE column1 = 'abc';
.
.
.
```

Now copy these `DELETE` commands and execute all.

---

**Note:**
In other way, you can write a stored program where you can turn these `generated command strings` into executable command/query through `prepare statement`.

But you can prefer the easiest way I've suggested above in order to bypass complexity.

Comment: No you won't get an error. If the specific entry doesn't exist then there's nothing to delete. It will just run silently.

Answer (score 0):

Create a cursor to iterate over varieble.
1. You can select a list of tables SHOW tables ----> To variable
2. Create a cursor http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/
3. Run cursor with the code that you want!

Best regards!